# Widget onUpdate, onReceive

Tags: android, android-widget

I initialize some arrays in an onUpdate() method and after that, using an intent and a button, I try to call onReceive() function which runs fine but cannot access arrays set in onUpdate() method. Why is that? Those array's are object variables and are declared public.
Am I missing something?

```
package net.aerosoftware.widgettest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WidgetTest extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
    public HashMap<Integer, String> channelsImages;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        Log.e("UPDATE", "Start");   
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

        channelsImages = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        channelsImages.put(0, "one");
        channelsImages.put(1, "two");

        Intent active = new Intent(context, WidgetTest.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);       
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonclick, actionPendingIntent);

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
        Log.e("UPDATE", "End");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.e("RECEIVE", "Start 2");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) 
        {
            try
            {
                Log.e("SIZE", "Size Of channel array: "+channelsImages.size());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("ON_RECIEVE_ERROR", " "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.e("RECEIVE", "End");
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"? Do you get any kind of exception? the content is empty?

Comment: can you add the code to your question, that would make things easier.

Comment: do you have only one instance of this widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a different instance of AppWidgetProvider (since it extends BroadcastReceiver)

API: `"A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active."`

You can use a service in order to avoid that.

Comment: I have a refresh button in my widget, which I would like to fire "onUpdate" in the widget. Can I just do that in the AppWidgetProvider or do I have to use a pendingclickevent? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the AppWidgetProvider API:

onReady():
"This is called for every broadcast and **before** each of the above callback methods. You normally don't need to implement this method because the default AppWidgetProvider implementation filters all App Widget broadcasts and calls the above methods as appropriate."

which means that onReceive() get invoked before onUpdate(), that's why you are getting null

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html

Comment: Nope, I know that, I use a receiver after I set the data with 

if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER))